# Android espresso maven and gradle setup

Tags: android, maven, ui-testing, android-espresso

Does any one have an example of maven setup of the new Android UI test framework called [espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso) ?

Answer (score 3):

[Quality Tools for Android](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/Quality-Tools-for-Android) now proposes both a maven and gradle setup example for android-test-kit/espresso.

To launch the espresso tests you can use either :

- mvn -P espresso
- gradle :android-sample-espresso-tests:connectedCheck

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the Java 7 compiler (even though the code compiles with -source & -target set to 1.5). (JDK6 and JDK1.5 may have [problems](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=1&can=1)).

Then you'll need to setup maven-android-sdk-deployer. Instructions are here:

https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer

After that it should just be a mvn install.

Eventually the artifacts will be available as an SDK extra. This is a developer preview right now :)

Comment: Where did you hear that JDK 7 is needed ? And up to now the espresso artifacts are not available. I can't say whether they will ever be available via the SDK manager or via maven central (and then installable via sdk deployer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 5 minutes set up of gradle setup of Espresso (in Android Studio), together with github example https://medium.com/p/c476d3b5ba45

Answer (score -1):

Also take a look at Jake Wharton's Gradle-port of Espresso. That may be a better intermediary step until the original library is updated with Gradle support.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso

Add the dependency to your `build.gradle` to get it working:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3'
```

Check http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton.espresso/espresso for the latest version.

Comment: Title asks "maven and gradle setup"